# Jasper Reports print report path on page

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReport 5.6 to design reports. 
Is there any way to print report path on a bottom of the page.
I have tried with buit-in Parameters. But I actually don't know how to do this.
I want to show examples;
    `BaseDir: http://localhost:8080/MyReports`
    `ReportFile: http://localhost:8080/MyReports/myreport.jasper`

Thank You,
Supun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

passing a parameter to the report should serve the purpose here.

```
String reportFileName = "your jasper path";
...
Map jasperParameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("reportFilePath",reportFileName);
```

In jrxml, you will have do the following.

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
...>
<parameter name="reportFilePath" class="java.lang.String"/>
...
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
            <![CDATA[$P{reportFilePath}]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```

You may refer to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_parameters.htm) example for using the parameters.